# how can I convert Javascript List of properties to List of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of properties like this

```
[{"ID":"0"},{"Day":""},{"Time":""},{"Type":"Both"},{"Status":"false"},
 {"ID":"0"},{"Day":""},{"Time":""},{"Type":"Both"},{"Status":"false"}]
```

I would like to convert them to something like this

```
[{"ID":"0","Day":"","Time":"","Type":"Both","Status":"false"},
{"ID":"0","Day":"","Time":"","Type":"Both","Status":"false"}]
```

This is one problem that i face nearly everytime converting a form to json and submitting it to a controller with complex type.

Comment: how are you converting your form to json?

Comment: I would think that it can't be assumed that the actual data will always be so neat and orderly, right? Could there be missing keys, or an altered order at times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if an object contains the key `ID` and build a new object with all following objects.

```js
var data = [{ ID: "0" }, { Day: "" }, { Time: "" }, { Type: "Both" }, { Status: "false" }, { ID: "0" }, { Day: "" }, { Time: "" }, { Type: "Both" }, { Status: "false" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if ('ID' in o) {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o));
        } else {
            Object.assign(r[r.length - 1], o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is one weird input,..

With the following I'm assuming there is always an ID, and it comes first.  As that data structure has no way of splitting the properties.

```js
var a = [{"ID":"0"},{"Day":""},{"Time":""},{"Type":"Both"},{"Status":"false"},
 {"ID":"0"},{"Day":""},{"Time":""},{"Type":"Both"},{"Status":"false"}];
 
var 
 ret = [],
 c = null;
a.forEach((r) => {
  if (r.ID) { c = {}; ret.push(c); }
  let k = Object.keys(r)[0];
  c[k] = r[k];
});

console.log(ret);
```